# Check if there's any string after a character

Tags: javascript, html, string

I want to find out, how can i see if there's any character/string after a specific string part from a string. My question sounds ambiguous but here's my real example:

I can have 2 urls :
http://domain/classAdd?itemId=1123123
or http://domain/classAdd?ItemId=

I want to put a condition in HTML regarding the url, to have specific header on my site.
How can i check if the url has a itemId or not?

At moment i'm getting only :`location.indexOf('classAdd?itemId=') == -1`  I tried to verify the length but doesn't work. I searched a lot but i didn't find anything to answer my question, only how to get Specific string from a string. My Id is dynamic and the substring won't work

Thank you guys.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you need to do? Check if `itemId` is present and if yes, get its value?

Comment: I want to know only if there's anything after `itemId`, i don't need it's value

Comment: Try `/\?(?:[^&]*&)*itemId=[^&]/.test(str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if this

```
window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('classAdd?itemId=') + 16)
```

gives you the itemId

Comment: Can i know why +16 ?

Comment: Are talking about guid's length?

Comment: That's the length of 'classAdd?itemId='. indexOf get's you the starting position of the substring and you neded to add it's length. Please check my answer edit.

Comment: yes, the code works, but i will have a dynamic domain and dynamic page 'classAdd'

Comment: i need to check if there's anything after "itemId=" part

Comment: window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('itemId=') + 7)

Comment: `window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('itemId=') + 7)` works well, but how can i see if there's something after itemId, i don't need it's value. I've got this line into an If statement into a `ng-show', and if there's something after itemId= i'll include an html , if not i'll include another html

Comment: just check if
 
window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf(‌​'itemId=') + 7) != ''

I don't use Angular, but I'm sure you can squeeze this in.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
    var indexOfEqual = window.location.href.indexOf("=");
    if(indexOfEqual < window.location.href.length) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think this is too general. What if there was e.g. OrderId= instead of ItemId=, it would still return true when really it should return false in TrulyXax's case.